# How to show native alert in cocos2D android?

Tags: android, cocos2d-android

I am creating a game in cocos2D android. I need to have an alert at the end of my game. 
Can I do this in cocos2D android?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this with JNI using the showMessageBoxJNI(const char * pszMsg, const char * pszTitle) method in the MessageJni.cpp class (in /cocos2dx/platform/android/jni). Simply import MessageJni.cpp in the class where you want to add an alert:

```
#include "./cocos2dx/platform/android/jni/MessageJni.h" // Note: this is a relative path, take care to the beginnin of the path "./" or "././" or etc..

showMessageBoxJNI("My alert message", "My alert title"); //Add this where you want in your class
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use menu for that. I think it is better option. on doing this, you can put click even to game over.when your game s over write below code

```
CCMenuItemFont item6 = CCMenuItemFont.item("Game over", this, "gameover");
            CCMenuItemFont.setFontSize(14);
            item6.setColor( new ccColor3B(0,0,0));
            CCMenu menu = CCMenu.menu(item6);
            menu.alignItemsVertically();
            addChild(menu);
```

and onclick of that menu this write below function. it will be called onclick.

```
public void gameover()
    {
        try {
            CCScene scene = nextlevellayer.scene();
            CCDirector.sharedDirector().pushScene(scene);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```